# Using .NET awesomium webview proxy can't load https

Tags: c#, .net, webview, awesomium

I'm using .NET awesomium webview

```
this.webView.LoginRequest += onLoginRequest;

public void onLoginRequest(object sender, LoginRequestEventArgs e)
        {
            // Proxy Login
            e.Username = itemInfo.proxyInfo.proxyAccount;
            e.Password = itemInfo.proxyInfo.proxyPwd;
            e.Handled = EventHandling.Modal;
            e.Cancel = false;
        }
```

and proxy login http page loadingFrameComplete's HTML is right.

But, Something after

`this.webView.Source = new Uri("https://...");` <= go to https page

that HTML is only

"html body /html /body"

someone help!!